# how to instantiate an NSLayoutConstraint in swift? (Xcode 6.1.1)

Tags: xcode, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I'm getting an error "Extra argument in call" pointing at the first parameter.

```
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    let imageHeight = 10.0
    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(imageView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: imageHeight)
```

I've also tried using `item: imageView,...`, but I get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that imageHeight is double, but the constructor expects a CGFloat, so try

```
let imageHeight: CGFloat = 10.0
```

and looks like there is one more little thing:

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: imageHeight)
```

you left the item before imageView, but you've mentioned that.